# Task Schedule failing despite having the correct login info

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2016

So quick backstory, we had an issue with one of our domain controllers that caused us to uninstall an update Microsoft pushed out earlier this month. After uninstalling that update any scheduled tasks we have on that specific domain controller that runs whether the account is logged in or not fails with an error value of  2147943726, so I figured I probably had the password wrong for the service account, I reconfirmed the account login info by logging into the account via my pc so i know I have the right password but the task continues to fail. I can run tasks from task scheduler if its not using the flag "run whether user is logged on or not" but if I do that it fails with that error value. Is there a way to repair the task scheduler application or rebuild it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on windows 10 non domain pc.
Is there a way to clear out saved credentials?

When you look at Event Viewer - Security you can see two entries.

Credential Manager credentials were read.

```
Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       MACHINE01$
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
    Read Operation:     Enumerate Credentials

This event occurs when a user performs a read operation on stored credentials in Credential Manager.
```

And then you see a second event

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       MACHINE01$
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Type:         4

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC000006A

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x80c
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   -
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```